# Question about the decomposability of the radical.

Tags: representation-theory

Let $A$ be an algebra over an algebraically closed field $K$ and $M$ an indecomposable $A$-module. Suppose that $M$ is indecomposable. Can we conclude that $\operatorname{rad}M$ is indecomposable? Thank you very much.

Comment: I think this question is too simple.  Have you considered the Kronecker algebra?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Aaron noted it is quite easy to construct very small counterexamples like the path algebra of the Kronecker quiver $1\stackrel{2}{\to} 2$, where the $2$ indicates that there are two arrows from $1$ to $2$. Or the path algebra of the quiver $A_3$ with non-linear orientation: $2\leftarrow 1\to 3$ or the algebra $k[x,y]/(x^2,y^2,xy)$. In each case the projective module $P_1$ provides a counterexample to your question.

One may ask what algebras satisfy that the radical of every indecomposable (left and right) module $M$ is again indecomposable. These are precisely the Nakayama algebras. An algebra is called a **Nakayama algebra** if every left and every right indecomposable module has a unique composition series (there are several equivalent characterisations).

If $A$ is not a Nakayama algebra. Then there is a vertex in the quiver of $A$ in which two arrows start (or end, this is left and right case). Then take the projective module associated to the corresponding vertex. Its quite obvious that its radical splits into as many direct summands as arrows start in the quiver.

Suppose $A$ is a Nakayama algebra. Suppose there is an indecomposable module such that the radical splits. Then one reaches a contradiction as one can construct two composition series, one having the top of each of the summands as a composition factor.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Thanks. Fixed.